# Why is dependency injection within an integration test failing when developing my grails plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, dependency-injection, integration-testing, grails-2.3

When using a generated Integration test (grails create-integration-test package.ServiceName) I am unable to use the injected service in the test - in a grails plugin.

It throws a very unhelpful NullPointerException

However, the very same process - but used in a grails app (grails create-app) works no problem at all.

You can duplicate this by:

`> grails create-plugin myServicePlugin`

`>grails test-app` //Passes as expected

`>grails create-service testing.DummyService`

Alter `\myServicePlugin\test\unit\testing\DummyServiceSpec.groovy`
Change

```
void "test something"() {
}
```

To

```
void "test something"() {
    expect:
    def x = true
}
```

`>grails test-app` //Passes

`>grails create-integration-test testing.DummyService`

Alter `\myServicePlugin\test\integration\testing\DummyServiceSpec.groovy`
Change

```
void "test something"() {
}
```

To

```
void "test something"() {
    expect:
    def x = true
}
```

`>grails test-app integration:` //Passes as expected

All good so far. Now to edit the `DummyService` to do something errmm.. Dummy-ish

Alter `\myServicePlugin\grails-app\services\testing\DummyService.groovy`

Add

```
def dummySpit(){
    return true
}
```

after `def serviceMethod(){}`

Now to inject the service into the test Spec

Alter `\myServicePlugin\test\integration\testing\DummyServiceSpec.groovy`

Add `def dummyService`

Below

```
class DummyServiceSpec extends Specification {
```

And change the `"test something"` method body to:

```
expect:
    assert dummyService.dummySpit()
```

And this is where the world falls over.

`>grails test-app integration:`

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.5
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
...............
|Compiling 1 source files
........
|Running without daemon...
.......................................
|Compiling 1 source files
.
|Running 1 integration test...
|Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
Failure:  |
test something(testing.DummyServiceSpec)
 |
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testing.DummyServiceSpec.test something(DummyServiceSpec.groovy:22)
|Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
.Tests FAILED 
|
 - view reports in G:\workspace\myServicePlugin\target\test-reports
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: I know this was my first SO post.. but why the down-vote on the question? I can understand down-voting an answer... but the question? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Edited question by removing trivial stuffs and emphasizing on the gist of the problem.

Comment: Whats at line 22 of DummyServiceSpec?

Answer (score 0):

At some stage the `create-plugin` malarkey has stopped including hibernate as a dependency.

If you add hibernate back in as a dependency, the above integration test should run. 
ie.

Alter `\myServicePlugin\grails-app\conf\BuildConfig.groovy`

Add `runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7"` to the `plugins {}` block

*NOTE* Taking into account the answer by @dmahapatro - it would be best practice to not export the hibernate plugin. So to avoid this you can:

```
test (":hibernate:3.6.10.7"){
    export = false
}
```

`>grails test-app integration:`

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.5
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
........
|Installing zip hibernate-3.6.10.7.zip...
...
|Installed plugin hibernate-3.6.10.7
....................
|Compiling 1 source files
.......
|Compiling 5 source files
...........
|Running without daemon...
.............................................
|Compiling 1 source files
.
|Running 1 integration test...
|Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
|Completed 1 integration test, 0 failed in 0m 0s
.
|Tests PASSED - view reports in G:\workspace\myServicePlugin\target\test-reports
```

Comment: You should not be doing that.

Comment: @dmahapatro Do you approve of the solution if the plugin is included using the `test` scope and `export=false` ?

Comment: If I were you I would not use it only to pass my tests and unless there is a requirement. :) It depends on your usage, you can go ahead if it is not posing any problem.